# An elementary question about cardinal arithmetic without AC

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Suppose $|X|=2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$, $A \subset X$ and $|A|=2^{\aleph_0}$. Is it possible to prove that $|X \setminus A|=2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ without using the axiom of choice and its consequences?

Comment: Yes, it's not the question in the title of the duplicate. But the accepted answer gives a solution which covers your question as well.